# A way to enable flash for specific sites only?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, flash

Using Firefox or Chrome...
Is there a way to control which sites are allowed to run flash and disable it for all others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The procedure for the current version of Chrome is detailed below.

1. Open a tab with `chrome://flags` and verify the the following are set to **Default** : **Prefer HTML over Flash** and **Run all Flash content when Flash setting is set to “allow”**
2. Open another tab with `chrome://components` and under **Adobe Flash Player**, click **Check for update** and wait for it to finish
3. Click on the Chrome menu button at the top-right and then on **Settings**
4. Click on **Show Advanced Settings**
5. Under **Privacy** click on **Content Settings**
6. In the dialog, under **Flash** ensure that **Ask first before allowing sites to run Flash (recommended)** is selected (don't do **Allow sites to run Flash**)
7. Now Flash is allowed and you need to enable it for your specific sites
8. The hard way to specify an allowed site is under **Content Settings – Flash** to click on the **Manage exceptions** button and add each site's URL with **Behavior** set to **Allow**
9. The easy way to allow a site is to go to it and then click on the little icon to the left of the URL in the address bar, and set **Flash** to **Always allow on this site** instead of the default which does not work in the latest version of Chrome.

[image]

More detailed instructions with screenshots can be found in
[this article](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/google-softwaretips/enable-flash-chrome-specific-websites/).

Comment: How do I allow flash from my pc but not from the internet?

Comment: @Efekan: This is by site, so allow the local URL but not the Internet one.

Comment: I tried doing what you do and it works for single flashes. It's been added in the settings menu like so `file:///D:/swf/myswf.swf`. But I couldn't manage to get it working on a folder. What i want is something like `file:///D:/swf/*` or just `file:///D:/swf`. Whenever I add it like `file:///D:/swf` it changes it to `file:///swf`.

Comment: Interesting: (1) Does it work at all for local content? (2) Does `file:///swf` work? (3) Try to use point 8 (Manage exceptions) with an asterisk.

Comment: (1) It works when you give in the exact name e.g. `file:///D:/swf/myswf.swf`. (2) `file:///swf` does not work at all. Tried putting the flashes on my two drives. `C:` and `D:` inside swf folder both didn't work. (3) `file:///*` does not work. Whenever I type in `file:///D:/*` it  shows it  as valid but when I press Enter key it removes the `D:` part and just becomes `file:///*`. Same issue with `C:`

Comment: @Efekan: I have seen reports that the Chrome developers don't like local content for Flash. So that option might be suffering neglect. You might need to move on to another browser.

Answer (score 12):

You could use an add-on to do this.

[NoScript Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noscript/)

[Flashblock Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/flashblock/)

[Flashblock Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl)

Comment: Wow, Flashblock seems like just what I'm looking for. NoScript is a bit overkill.

Comment: The Flashblock Chrome link appears to be dead. :(

Comment: Google Chrome blocks flash by default now. Even if the URL for Flashblock Chrome wasn't dead, it probably wouldn't work on modern versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to aforementioned solutions, for Firefox there is a native (built-in) one too:

Click on the **icon in the beginning of the address bar** in Firefox
[image]

1. More Information...
2. Permissions
3. Active Plugins

And now you have full control over this page.

Comment: This is very useful if you simply want to disable Flash Player on a specific site.

Comment: Chrome has a very similar mechanism as of the time of writing this comment.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Opera who wish to do the same thing, you can shut off plug-ins (which includes Adobe Flash) for any web site by following these simple steps:

1. Right-click on the web page
2. Select "Edit Site Preferences..."
3. Activate the "Content" tab
4. Disable the "Enable plug-ins" checkbox
5. Click the "OK" button

To enable again, repeat the above steps but read step 4 above as "Enable" instead of "Disable."

Answer (score 1):

I like the accepted answer, but the following method works well for when you want to give wildcard approval for domain.

1. Go to: `chrome://settings/content/flash`
2. Click **Add** and enter the site or pattern:
   [image: Add a flash site]